# Angular indeterminate checkbox directive ng-change issue

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, angularjs-directive

I am trying to implement the angular **data-indeterminate-checkbox** directive in my application from the link below.

[Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cjwprostar/M4vGj/6/)

I have added **ng-change** to both the parent and the children checkboxes (same event) which updates the columns in a table below. The problem is when I check/uncheck the child checkboxes, the columns appear and dissapear fine and it works ok, but when I click the select all checkbox, the action is inverted. That is, when select all is checked, all columns hidden and when unchecked, all columns are visible.

In the snippet for the directive from the fiddle link mentioned above, in the else part, if I change the `modelCtrl.$setViewValue(hasChecked);` to `modelCtrl.$setViewValue(true);`, as shown in code below, the uncheck part works, i.e when I uncheck 'Select All', all columns are hidden but when I check it, nothing happens and it does not go to the `ng-change` event. Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance and Happy New Year 2016!!

```
// Determine which state to put the checkbox in

if (hasChecked && hasUnchecked) {
    element.prop('checked', false);
    element.prop('indeterminate', true);
    if (modelCtrl) {
        modelCtrl.$setViewValue(false);
    }
} else {
    element.prop('checked', hasChecked);
    element.prop('indeterminate', false);
    if (modelCtrl) {
        modelCtrl.$setViewValue(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: I set the `modelCtrl.$setViewValue(true);` and I don't see an error in behaviour. Checkbox goes to unchecked and clicking on Select All again selects all related checkboxes. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Thanks for your response. The problem is not with selecting all the checkboxes using Select All, but the **ng-change** event i have added to Select All. When i check select all, the columns in the table which i am trying to refresh in my code disappear which should happen when select all is unchecked. So the event behavior is opposite. Does that make sense now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by putting a condition on the ng-change event of the checkboxes. Here is the snippet - (as per the example fiddle):

```
if(!$scope.model.people[0].allEaten){ 
    $timeout(function(){ 
        updateModel(); 
        refreshColumns(); 
    },2000); 
} else { 
    $timeout(function(){ 
        refreshColumns(); 
    },2000); 
}
```

But please feel free to comment if there is a better answer to this.
Thank you!